# current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC' SQL Server equivalent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, timestamp, syntax

What is the equivalent of the Postgres "current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC'" in SQL Server?

How do I select the current timestamp in UTC in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the `SYSUTCDATETIME` function, which is used like this:

```
SELECT SYSUTCDATETIME();
```

It returns the current system date and time, adjusted to UTC time.

This seems similar to what the postgres equivalent does (except it looks like `current_timestamp` includes timezone information, while `SYSUTCDATETIME` does not).

If you need the time zone information, you can use a similar construction in SQL Server with the `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET` function:

```
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

The results look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the results of calling the above-mentioned system functions, showing the results are the same with the exception that sysdatetimeoffset includes the time zone offset]

Comment: `GETUTCDATE()` also works if don't require as much fractional second precision. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16